# Compose: Can you pass pointer events to other composables?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make some overlays in specific positions highlighting and outlining text areas in a BasicTextField, while being able to double tap to open that section in another view. I've gotten a nice outline and highlight by making multiple canvas' clipped to the size of their content overtop of the BasicTextField. id like to change the colors and such of these highlights as they are tapped. thats easy, the issue is that the canvas consumes the touch event and the cursor never gets placed/moved to the location the user taps in the canvas. So is there a way one can pass a touch event to another composable? I couldn't find any way to have the canvas' detect the pointer event without consuming it or that would be smoother.

Here's what i've got going on so far, slimmed down a bit

```
 Box() {
 BasicTextField(
 // just somestyling modifiers
 )
 }
 
 Canvas(
 modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
               awaitPointerEventScope {
                  while (true) {
                     val event = awaitPointerEvent()

                     when (event.type) {
                        PointerEventType.Release -> {
                        // Do Something
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
 ) {
       // Draw the overlays
   }
```

Not really sure how to accomplish this to be honest so a bunch of googling has returned nothing that I could use to get the pointer event to both these composables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say I have a screen named `HomeScreen`.

inside of `HomeScreen` I have a `Card` like this:

```
    var currentPosition by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset(0F, 0F))
    }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.onPointerEvent(PointerEventType.Move) { 
            currentPosition = it.changes.first().position) 
    )
```

you can simply have access to `currentPosition` every where in screen